# Emberjs add target to link-to

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying the use the link-to helper to open a dynamic link in a new tab, but so far it's not working.

I'm using LinkView for that and I can see the target attribute in my link, but it doesn't open the url in a new tab but in the current one.

Here is my code :

The template :

```
{{#link-to "page.edit" id target="_blank"}}EDIT{{/link-to}}
```

The LinkView :

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['target']
});
```

This is what it generate when I inspect it :

```
<a id="ember468" class="ember-view" href="#/pages/1/edit" target="_blank">EDIT</a>
```

Do I miss something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `target` is already part of `Ember.LinkView`. Get rid of the reopen code and the rest is working: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sumiwa/1/edit

Comment: Ah yes okay, I was using an outdated version of ember that's why it didn't work.. Thank you !